# Can we add Permission Set Name criteria in Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder, permission-sets

[image]

I am trying to add a criteria which checks for permission set names in process builder. Like we can check
User.Profile.Name = 'abcP'
Can we check
User.PermissionSet = 'abcPS' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not do this in Process Builder.  But you can reference a Custom Permission using `$Permission.xxx`

```
IF(some condition &&
   $Permission.MyCustomPermission)
```

If you wanted to check possession of a Permission Set, then use Lightning Flow and query the `PermissionSetAssignment` object (a junction between `User` and `PermissionSet`)

[Schema for Permission Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm)